# Can I save some JSON data from a file of 1MB in Azure table storage?

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I want to store and retrieve some JSON data from a file of size upto 1MB. Should I use Azure table storage or blob storage?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An entity in Table Storage (equivalent to a row in a table in RDBMS) can be up to 1MB, however individual attributes in an entity (equivalent to columns) can only be 64KB. You can spread your JSON over multiple attributes, however this would only work if you can guarantee that every file ever is guaranteed to be well below 1MB.  (You will need some room for your system attributes like PartitionKey, RowKey, etc).

I would suggest looking into another store: DocumentDB, MongoDB or perhaps even a Redis cache that you back with another non-volatile storage. Maybe a Azure Sql DB will suffice, now that it has support for retrieving JSON values.

Another solution would be saving the files in BLOB storage and referencing them from the table storage. If you would need to look up multiple files at once, this might be slower though.

Comment: I have to consider the cost because I will have thousands of such JSON files. Continually operating on such data like retrieving and updating in DocumentDB would be expensive. I'm leaning towards BLOB storage.

Answer (score 2):

+1 for the solution to store the data in blob storage and referencing the blob uri in the table. You can also do is update the blob metadata properties with the unique identifiers of the table so that even if you just retrieve the blobs you can get what entity it belongs to.